# OptaPlanner Collectors Composition: Need Implementation Guidance

Tags: java, constraints, optaplanner

Consulting [OptaPlanner Docs on Constraint Streams](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/constraint-streams/constraint-streams.html#collectorsComposition), I have been trying to implement a ConstraintCollector to use in a groupBy() call for a constraint stream. I am unable to understand what inputs the collector should take and its outputs.

My model is assigning `Employee`s to `Shift`s. `Employee`s consist of one of many `Tracer`s. Each `Tracer` consists of one of many `Isotope`s and a `batchesPerProduction` attribute. Each `Isotope` has a `Contract` only allowing so many productions of that `Isotope` per day. Each production of an `Isotope` can produce 1 or more batches of `Tracer`, dependant on which `Tracer`. Each `Shift` uses 1 batch of a `Tracer`.

I need a constraint that will sum all batches of each `Tracer` for each date to ensure the number of `Isotope` productions needed to produce those `Tracer` batches doesn't exceed the contract daily maximum for `Isotope` productions.

```
@PlanningEntity
public class Shift {

    @PlanningVariable
    private Employee employee = null;

    private Isotope isotope;

    private OffsetDateTime startDateTime;
    private OffsetDateTime endDateTime;

}

public class Employee {

    private Tracer tracer;

}

public class Tracer {

    private Isotope isotope;

    private Long batchesPerProduction;

}


public class Isotope {

    private Contract contract;

}

public class Contract {

    private Integer maximumProductionsPerDay;

}
```

I believe my approach for the `Constraint` should be:

1. ForEach `Tracer`
2. Join each `Shift` whose `Employee` equals the `Tracer`
3. GroupBy (`Tracer`, date) and Aggregate by count(`Shifts` per `Tracer`) / `Tracer::getBatchesPerProduction`
4. GroupBy (`Isotope`, date) and Aggregate by sum(productions)

`Isotope` productions = count(`Shifts` per `Tracer`) / `Tracer::getBatchesPerProduction`

I am not sure if the ConstraintCollector should be a BiConstraintCollector with (tracer, day) as inputs:

```
public static <A,B> BiConstraintCollector<Tracer, LocalDate, ?, Long>
        batchesToProductions(ToLongFunction<A,B> groupValueMapping) {
            return compose(countLongBi(groupValueMapping), (tracer, day, countLongBi) -> {
                    return (long) Math.ceil(countLongBi / tracer.getBatchesPerProduction());
            });
    }
```

or a TriConstraintCollector with (tracer, day, shiftCountDaily) as inputs:

```
public static <A,B,C> TriConstraintCollector<Tracer, LocalDate, Long, ?, Long>
        batchesToProductions(ToLongFunction<A,B,C> groupValueMapping) {
            return compose((tracer, day, shiftsCount) -> {
                    return (long) Math.ceil(shiftsCount / tracer.getBatchesPerProduction());
            });
    }
```

I have not been able to make either work and I do not know how I would use this collector in a groupBy method in the Constraint Stream. Admittedly, I am quite new to Java and I am having trouble understanding the Stream from the [interface](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latestFinal/optaplanner-javadoc/org/optaplanner/core/api/score/stream/bi/BiConstraintCollector.html) to the compose methods of the [ConstraintCollectors](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latestFinal/optaplanner-javadoc/org/optaplanner/core/api/score/stream/ConstraintCollectors.html#compose(org.optaplanner.core.api.score.stream.bi.BiConstraintCollector,org.optaplanner.core.api.score.stream.bi.BiConstraintCollector,java.util.function.BiFunction))

Below is my attempt at a Constraint that would use the above ConstraintCollector method.

```
Constraint dailyProductionsMustNotExceedContractMaximum(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(Tracer.class)
                .join(Shift.class,
                equal(Function.identity(), Shift::getTracerForEmployee))
                .groupBy(
                        (tracer,shift) -> tracer,
                        (tracer,shift) -> shift.getStartDateTime().toLocalDate(),
                        (tracer,shift) -> **batchesToProductions(tracer,shift)**)

                .groupBy(
                        (tracer, day, productions) -> tracer.getIsotope(),
                        (tracer, day, productions) -> day,
                        (tracer, day, productions) -> sum(productions)
                )
                .filter((isotope, day, productions) -> productions > isotope.getContract().getMaximumShiftsPerDay())
                .penalizeConfigurableLong(CONSTRAINT_DAILY_PRODUCTIONS_MUST_NOT_EXCEED_CONTRACT_MAXIMUM,
                        (isotope, day, productions) -> productions
                                - isotope.getContract().getMaximumShiftsPerDay());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd want to implement your own constraint collector. The constraint you outlined could be written like so:

```
forEach(Shift.class)
.groupBy(shift -> shift.employee.tracer,
    shift -> shift.startDateTime.toLocalDate(),
    count())
.groupBy((tracer, date, count) -> tracer.isotope,
    (tracer, date, count) -> date,
    sum((tracer, date, count) -> count / tracer.batchesPerProduction)
.penalize((isotope, date, sum) -> ...)
```

Note that if any of the non-entities become entities, this will result in score corruptions. They are not in a `forEach` nor in a `join`, so the stream will not be re-evaluated when they change.